# Transferring information from ListBox to another ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a ListBox where on runtime it lists information from an xml. When I select a certain value from the list, I want to be able to add the selected value into the other empty listbox when I click a add button for example

What are the methods invloved. thanks

Comment: show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this:

First Create an object to hold the selected item from the main ListBox

```
object _SelectedItem = null;
```

then go to the SelectedIndexChanged event of your main ListBox and add this code

```
_SelectedItem = MainListbox.SelectedItem;
```

to add the selected item to the other list via your Button use this code

```
TheOtherListBox.Items.Add(_SelectedItem);
```

You can also add the new item directly from your main ListBox SelectedIndexChanged event like this

```
TheOtherListBox.Items.Add(MainListbox.SelectedItem);
```

Next time post some code, so we can see that you at least tried.

Comment: I have tried exactly this, and it has an error saying object does not exist in current context. is it because I created the object in the Main

Comment: try changing the Modifier from **object _SelectedItem = null;** to **internal static object _SelectedItem = null;** this way you can acces **_SelectedItem** from anywhere inside the project.

Comment: It says there is no such term as 'internal static'

Comment: that's not possible it works fine on C#3.5 & C#4.0 you're not using it right